# nwjs chrome extension issue

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

I set a domain to my nwjs app, but there's a problem with generated name (chrome-extensions://namesetinpackagejson.it), in google drive apis I can enable only url that start with "http://". How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think that best way to solve it to have a HTTP server set up in your code that will listen to http://localhost:«any-port-number». Set the url of Google drive to http://localhost:«that-same-port-number». You should in your server 'handle' the response from Google Drive.

Does this help?